# Spark SQLContext load multiple files

Tags: apache-spark

I want to download current and previous month json files only or last 10 day json files.

```
val jobNonProdTable = sqlContext.jsonFile(s"somepath/pdate=$year/[01-02]/*")
```

This doesn't seems to be working.